# Editing/Redefining a Constant String: Yes I'm aware of the contradiction

Tags: c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

I am attempting to change a constant variables value, *yes I am aware of the contradiction of what I am doing* but there is a method to my madness.

You see I am writing in a language very similar to **C**/C++ called 4dm but it doesn't allow any code outside of functions so I am trying to overcome this by using pre-processor commands. The reason is so I can achieve a form of specialisation in the language. The first step of this involves being able to edit a constant string.

Even though this is a different language, the preprocessor operates in exactly the same way as C and C++ compilers:

```
#define MY_STR "abc"
#define CONCAT(s) \
    #define TEMP MY_STR \  // store MY_STR in TEMP_STR
    #undef MY_STR \        // undefine MY_STR
    #define MY_STR TEMP s  // redefine MY_STR so it contains the old value plus the new one

CONCAT(def)
printf("%s\n", MY_STR);  // should hopefully print out "abc def"
```

The following is a simple attempt at concatenating a string but I get a compile error saying `MY_STR is not defined` any ideas how to fix this?

```
#define MY_STR abc
#define TEMP MY_STR
#undef MY_STR
#define MY_STR TEMP def

void test()
{
    print(MY_STR);
}
```

Comment: Modifying a constant string causes undefined behaviour in C++, but what you are doing here is redefining a preprocessor macro, not modifying a `const string`. That's two totally different things. What is your question anyway?

Comment: You are headed for disappointment!  Give more information about what you are trying to achieve.  There may be some other way to achieve it.

Comment: @paddy I would explain it but it will take alot of text and take the question off on a tangent from concating/redefining constants to Recursion and Specification so I'll make a new question

Comment: "I am writting in a language very similar to C/C++ called 4dm"… considering C/C++ is not a well-defined language, and you seem to want to dance around language rules, you should probably clarify what you're using. Wikipedia and Google don't turn up any language spec.

Comment: By the way, the C preprocessor doesn't work that way and never did. You can't put a directive inside a macro.

Comment: @Potatoswatter ok is there any other way I could store MY_STR inside TEMP? Heres the langauage information: http://www.12dmodel.com/downloads/documentation/12d_progm.pdf

Comment: @JakeM You're heading for an XY problem. You have problem X, you think you can solve it using Y, so you ask about Y. But Y probably isn't the solution. We need a high-level description of what you're really trying to achieve, so we can tell you whether or not the preprocessor can do that. (If indeed what you have is a preprocessor conforming to the C or C++ standards.)

Answer (score 2):

In your first example, you're trying to expand a macro into a `#define` preprocessor command. You can't do that; the preprocessor produces `C` code (or whatever), and the various things that look like preprocessor directives in the macro expansion will actually not be preprocessor directives. That will produce an error, because `#` in a macro definition is the "stringify" operator, which must be followed by a macro parameter.
(Also, the `\` must be at the end of the line. You can't follow it with a comment.)

In your second example, When you write:

```
#define TEMP MY_STR
```

that's exactly what it does: it defines the macro `TEMP` as having the value `MY_STR` (not the macro expansion of `MY_STR`, just the six-character token `MY_STR`.

After that, you

```
#define MY_STR TEMP def
```

That defines the macro `MY_STR` as the two tokens `TEMP` and `def`.

Then you expand `MY_STR`:

```
print(MY_STR);
```

which causes it to be replaced with `TEMP def`. The expansion is run through the macro processor again, which causes `TEMP` to be replaced with `MY_STR`. That's run through the macro processor again, but this time `MY_STR` is *not* expanded because you cannot expand a macro within an expansion of that macro. So this time it stays as `MY_STR`, and you end up with:

```
print(MY_STR def);
```

`MY_STR` is not defined (a macro is not a definition), so the compiler complains that `MY_STR` is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

A good compiler will put a string constant in a block that will be marked as write protected, and any attempt to modify it will result in some kind of OS exception.

That's not what you're doing here though - you're defining a new string in terms of the old string. That would work in C and C++, and presumably works in your language as well.

Since you're defining your own language, you would know better than us how it will react!

Comment: please see the edit, it shows how the compiler reacts, saying the that MY_STR isn't defined. Not sure how to fix that error?

Comment: @JakeM The problem at that point is that you've defined `MY_STR` as `abc`, while it should be `"abc"` (note the double quotation marks).

Comment: @jogojapan Thanks I've added the quotation marks. But the compile error still occurs saying `MY STR not defined` inside the function test.

Answer (score 0):

About what you're trying to achieve with `CONCAT`, § 6.10.3.4 ¶3 of the C99 standard says (partial quote):

> The resulting completely macro-replaced preprocessing token sequence is not processed as a preprocessing directive even if it resembles one